# Escaped double quotes by slashes make browser load it enormously slow

Tags: php, apache, text, browser

I have recently faced with a very odd problem. I don't have any ideas where even look for a solution.

When I generate or upload static file with a textual content that contains a lot of escaped double quotes by slashes, it makes a browser load it very-very slowly.

You can check it yourself. For example, if you create a textual file with a repeated string `var=\"value\"`  of 35000 times, it will couse such behaviour.

I use Apache 2.4 to access a file via URL. It happends on:

- **Windows 7**: Chorme, Mozilla, Opera, IE Edge;
- **Windows XP**: Mozilla;

The intereting fact is that it works well in Safari on **MacOS**.

If you want to replicate the problem, you can use the following PHP code to generate such file:

`str_repeat( 'var=\\"value\\" ', 35000 )`

The weirdest part is: if you use single quotes, everything is fine.

Here are my own tests:

- A file with the repeated string `var=\"value\"`  of 35000 times has a size 478Kb and it takes 78 seconds for my browser to load it.
- A file with the repeated string `var=\'value\'`  of 35000 times has a size 478Kb and it takes 0.165 second for my browser to load it.

I use Apache on my local computer, so the Internet connection cannot be a problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I tried OS X Chrome 63 on my own computer, Windows 7 Chrome 63 and IE 11 on BrowserStack. The server is running NGINX.

Comment: My URL is http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test.txt

Comment: Thank you for the provided link! I tried it and it takes 55 seconds to load a file with a 550 KB size. If you don't believe, I can even record the video.

Comment: Please, do not remove the link, I will test it on my other devices.

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox on my Mac, it also came up instantly.

Comment: I have just tried it on other PC with Windows 7 and the same behaviour remains the same. It took 80 seconds to load the file. As I mentioned in the question, I checked it on MacOS and it worked well. It's only the problem with Windows.

Comment: Tomorrow I will check it on my friend's computer with Windows 10. Anyway, it's a big enigma!

Comment: Do you use a specific firewall or antivirus? That might be a pattern that triggers something and it takes a lot of time to check.

Comment: Yes, but I checked on two separate computers with Windows 7. The first one has Avast as antivirus, another - AVG. It's highly unlikely that both antivirus programs treat it in precisely the same way.